# Как правильно подключать стили к asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

В общем есть небольшой код, допустим

```css
.expand {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.etp{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-center">

        <div class="etp">
            <a>Page</a>
            <span class="expand">+</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Но стиль не меняется. Как правильно подключать стили к асп? Я видимо что-то не до конца сделал. Я сам в html+css почти не разбираюсь так что может я что-то неверно делаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключение стилей в asp.net делается так же как и в обычном html-файле без asp mvc - через вставку `<style type="text/css">...</style>`, их у вас нет.

В файле вашего представления/вью (расширение .cshtml) напишите:

```
<div class="text-center">

    <div class="etp">
        <a>Page</a>
        <span class="expand">+</span>
    </div>

</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .expand {
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .etp{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Обрамления html, body у вас вероятнее всего уже находятся в _Layout.cshtml

Если надо прописать css-файл -- то это лучше посмотрите в коде _Layout.cshtml раздел с link, он обычно выглядит примерно так:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"
          asp-fallback-href="~/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
</environment>
```